# Reproduzindo som com MIDI - Java

Tags: java

Escrevi um código para reproduzir um determinado som, porém não está reproduzindo.

```
package reprodutormusical;

public class TestDrive {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MiniMusicApp mini = new MiniMusicApp();
        mini.play();

    }

}
```

classe MiniMusicApp:

```
package reprodutormusical;
import javax.sound.midi.*;

public class MiniMusicApp {

    public void play() {
        try {
        // Cria uma anologia a um DVD Player
        Sequencer player = MidiSystem.getSequencer();
        // Cria um analogia ao CD que será tocado
        Sequence seq = new Sequence(Sequence.PPQ, 4);
        Track track = seq.createTrack();

        ShortMessage a = new ShortMessage();
        a.setMessage(144, 1, 44, 100);
        MidiEvent noteOn = new MidiEvent(a, 1);
        track.add(noteOn);

        ShortMessage b = new ShortMessage();
        a.setMessage(128, 1, 44, 100);
        MidiEvent noteOff = new MidiEvent(b, 16);
        track.add(noteOff);

        player.setSequence(seq);

        player.start();
        // Inseri uma pausa para dar ao som de reproduzir
        Thread.sleep(100 * 2);
        player.close();
        System.exit(0);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Apresenta essa excessão:

> jun 09, 2018 12:37:03 PM java.util.prefs.WindowsPreferences 
>   WARNING: Could not open/create prefs root node Software\JavaSoft\Prefs
>   at root 0x80000002. Windows RegCreateKeyEx(...) returned error code 5.
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: sequencer not open   at
>   com.sun.media.sound.RealTimeSequencer.start(Unknown Source)   at
>   reprodutormusical.MiniMusicApp.play(MiniMusicApp.java:26)     at
>   reprodutormusical.TestDrive.main(TestDrive.java:7)

Comment: Você tem um synth?

Comment: Sua placa de som tem porta MIDI?

Comment: Tá rodando como administrador?

Comment: Boa noite, estava verificando e a placa não possui suporte a MIDI, teria alguma outra classe do Java para trabalhar com som/

Comment: https://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/J8c_PlayingSound.html